# Printing the minuend and subtrahend in a Minimum Difference algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, array

I have a Minimum Difference algorithm, and I wanted to expand on it by printing the actual elements that were subtracted. I'm just wanting to know if this is the best way to do it.

```
public static int findMinimumDifference(int[] arr) {

    int minuend = 0; //initialize them here
    int subtrahend = 0; 
    Arrays.sort(arr); //sort the array first

    int difference = 0; 

    if (arr.length == 1) { 
        difference = arr[0]; 
    }
    if (arr.length > 1) { 
        difference = Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[1]); //This will give only positive integers for difference - e.g. 6 - 7 = -1 = 1

        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 < arr.length) { //as long as we're not at the end yet
                int temp = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]); // temp variable is assigned to difference of consecutive elements i and i + 1
                if (temp < difference) // if temp is the new minimum difference, assign difference to temp
                    difference = temp; 
                if(arr[i + 1] - arr[i] == difference) { 
                    minuend = arr[i + 1]; //Here's where I assign them
                    subtrahend = arr[i]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(arr.length == 1) { //If there's only one element it will 
                          //display arr[0] - 0 = arr[0]
                          //e.g. 12 - 0 = 12
        System.out.print(arr[0] + " - " + minuend + " = ");
    }
    else { //otherwise, show the subtraction
        System.out.print(minuend + " - " + subtrahend + " = ");
    }
    return difference;
    }
}
```

This is the output for two arrays as an example:

> ```
> int[] array1 = {5, 16, 3, 32, 6};
> int[] array2 = {13, 22, 37, 40, 11, 99, 100, 222, 1000, 101, 9999, 10000};
>
> The minimum differences in the arrays are: 
> 6 - 5 = 1
> 10000 - 9999 = 1
> ```

**NOTE**: I understand that second array actually has another subset (99, 100) that will equal 1. I just haven't figured out how to display both sets yet. I will work on that later.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sorting

[`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) performs an in-array sorting, which may not be desirable if the caller of your method isn't expecting so. You may want to make a copy of the input via [`Arrays.copyOf(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) first.

#### Calculation

```
int temp = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]);
if (temp < difference) /* ... */
```

Since you have sorted the array in ascending order, you have two possible approaches:

1. Leave `temp` as negative so that you're looking for the *largest* negative number, e.g. `-1` to find the *smallest* difference.
2. Use `arr[i + 1] - arr[i]` so that the comparison afterwards can remain the same.

Using `Math.abs()` is therefore unnecessary.

#### Initializing values and array references

You treat `arr.length = 1` differently from a multi-valued array when it comes to printing the value, but with some adjustment to how you initialize `minuend` and `difference`, you don't have to do so, e.g.:

```
int minuend = arr[0];
int difference = Integer.MAX;
```

In addition, consider storing just the difference and the array index where you have the smallest difference, so that you don't need to remember `subtrahend`.